# PHP FTP return to FTP-user Root folder

Tags: php, ftp, chdir

How can I return to the ftp users root folder. In this example it is /isi/ in my home/user/ dir.

```
        $location = $order;
        $real_location = $workflow_location =$leverancier;

        if (!@ftp_chdir($ftp_conn, $real_location)) {
            ftp_mkdir($ftp_conn, $real_location);
        }

        foreach($maps as $map) {
            $real_location = $real_location . '/' . $map;
            $workflow_location = $workflow_location . '~' . $map;

            if (!@ftp_chdir($ftp_conn, $real_location)) {
                ftp_mkdir($ftp_conn, $real_location);
                ftp_chdir($ftp_conn, $real_location);
            }

        }
        // ISI is the root folder
        if (ftp_chdir($ftp_conn, '/isi/')) { 
          echo "ftp_chdir successful\n";
        } else {
          echo "ftp_chdir not successful\n";
        }
        exit;
```

---------------------------------------------------------- EDIT ----------------------------------------------------------------

Not realy a clean way to do it, but putting this after the code is poster above did the trick. I counted the folders, this way I did know how many times I've to use the ftp_cdup function.

```
   $i = count($maps);
        $i++;
        while($i > 0) {
            ftp_cdup($ftp_conn);
            $i--;
        }
```

---------------------------------------------------------- EDIT2 ---------------------------------------------------------------

Other solution:

```
ftp_chdir($ftp_conn, '~');
```

Comment: You mean, `users HOME folder`? On Linux machines `~` simbolizes users home directory, so...  `ftp_chdir($ftp_conn, '~');` should do the thing.

Comment: That did the trick also, I think your solution is much better. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

On Linux machines You can address current user's home directory as `~`.

So, one of the possible solutions would be just using `ftp_chdir($ftp_conn, '~');`.

More on this topic:

- [ftp_chdir@php.net](https://www.php.net/ftp_cdup)
- *still lookin for official documentation entry for ~, ., .. etc.*